# What's a "Diamond Lane"?

Tags: american-cinema, sitcoms, curb-your-enthusiasm

At 18.17, S4 E6, Larry says:

> I picked her (a prostitute) up so I can use the diamond lane so I can get the stadium
>   in time for the game

What does this mean? Why couldn't he have taken the diamond lane without her?

Comment: Diamond Lane, also known as Car Pool lane, meaning 2 or more people must be in the car. Some exceptions are made for hybrid/electric vehicles, they are allowed in the lane with only 1 occupant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "diamond lane" is another name for a "HOV (High Occupancy Vehicle) Lane," so named because they are typically marked with diamonds painted on the pavement (and sometimes on lighted signs above them).

> A high-occupancy vehicle lane (also known as an HOV lane, carpool lane, diamond lane, 2+ lane, and transit lane or T2 or T3 lanes) is a restricted traffic lane reserved for the exclusive use of vehicles with a driver and one or more passengers, including carpools, vanpools, and transit buses. These restrictions may be only imposed during peak travel times or may apply at all times ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-occupancy_vehicle_lane))

These lanes are designed to encourage carpooling and using public transit, and typically have fewer cars present in them than the regular lanes usable by single-occupant vehicles. During rush hour periods, the traffic in them is commonly much lighter than that in the regular lanes, which leads to people attempting to "scam" their way into the lanes through use of items like blow-up dolls, mannequins, and the like to attempt to appear that they have a passenger present.

The implication of the line in the question is that the person speaking was driving a single-occupancy vehicle and would have been caught up in heavy, slow-moving traffic, preventing a timely arrival. He picked up the prostitute not because of her profession, but because she would be a second person in the vehicle, allowing him entry to the express/HOV/diamond lane and faster travel to his destination, where he would then let her out. He could also have found a friend to travel with him, or used a dummy of some sort; hiring a prostitute for a task well outside what's normally expected is a way to add humor to the situation.

Answer (score -3):

### A special driving lane reserved for specific types of traffic.

> **In the United States and Canada, a [diamond lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_lane) is a special lane
> on a street or highway that is reserved for specific types of traffic.
> These lanes are usually marked with white diamonds or lozenge, hence
> their name.** Diamond lanes are generally the right-most or left-most
> lane on the road. They are usually implemented to provide ways through
> traffic congestion, for safety reasons, and to encourage
> environmentally friendly transportation. A diamond lane may be
> intended for a specific type of traffic, or for several types. The
> intended use of a diamond lane is marked by traffic signs. In most
> areas, violating the rules of a diamond lane is punishable by a fine.

I haven't seen the episode to know the full context, but he needed this lane in order to get to the game on time.

Apparently this lane was reserved for prostitutes or he needed another person to use the lane, or at least that is what he is saying *is his excuse* for having the prostitute with him, as it's an mostly an illegal profession in the USA.

Comment: I haven't seen the series, so I don't know, but the criterium for using the lane might be as boring as "minimum 2 persons in the car". Picking up a prostitute is one way to meet that criterium.

Comment: Ya, that might true in some cases and could potentially relate here, since "carpool" or "buses" sometimes also gets these "high occupancy vehicle" lanes, but these lanes can be for bikes and horse and buggy too. I ended up answering the Q before it was edited to further ask about it's meaning in the episode, so I'm trying to compensate, but I also know that CYE is a dramedy so, I suspect there is suppose to be something "funny" about his response! :D

Comment: There is not going to be a lane reserved for people practicing an illegal profession.

Comment: I stated as much in my original answer, suggesting that it could be one punch line, but then updated to accommodate what @Henrik-stophurtingMonica suggested. Now I have changed it closer to my original answer again. As mentioned originally the Q didn't ask for context, just what the lane is. Since I didn't watch the episode or have more dialogue to go on, I can only speculate.